# Superposition theorem

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, superposition, linear-systems

Is superposition theorem applicable for circuits having semiconductor components like diodes, transistors, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superposition theorem is applicable only to linear and bilateral circuits. Diodes and trasistors are often not bilateral and linear.

Comment: I saw in some texts that superposition theorem is used in analyzing Dc,AC operations of transistor amplifier.Please comment on this.

Comment: Remember that you work in the linear zone; hence the name linear amplifier